# About AJAX, need to click submit button two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

My ajax code looks like this:

```
 $("#form").submit(function(event){

        var $form = $(this);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/blog/ajaxphp/registration_check.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {formData:serializedData},
            datetype: "JSON"
        });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if(jQuery.parseJSON(response).success==undefined){
                $form.unbind('submit');
                $form.submit();
            }
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        });
        event.preventDefault();


    });
```

Problem:
I need to click submit button twice otherwise  this form is not being submitted.
I tried using return false instead of `preventdefault` and also  tried `$form.unbind('submit');` but not working.

how to i make submit button to work by 1 click

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle showing the issue occurring?

Comment: do you have any validation script running for form?

Comment: @BrettWeber Is there no problem in code according to question ??

Comment: Do you have any further click or key events bind to your submit button? The submit event is triggered before the actual form is submitted, but might be triggered after other click events on child elements on the form. Maybe even an onclick attribute on the submitbutton. A jsfiddle might help the speculations, though.

Comment: I don't know about jsfiddle but can you help me by team veiwer?

Comment: is that form dynamically injected?

Answer (score 1):

In the request.done event, return true if success is not undefined. You may consider an alternative to unbinding and resubmitting the form when success is undefined, or removing that portion all together and just showing a message that says that the form could not be submitted and should be tried again. It's worth trying just to see if simplifying the process yields the results you want.

I would also remove event.preventDefault(); and just return false inside the request.fail event.

I assume you are doing all of this because you don't want to submit the form before the ajax call is finished, so you might want to try adding async: false to your $.ajax request:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event){

    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/blog/ajaxphp/registration_check.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {formData:serializedData},
        async: false,
        datetype: "JSON"
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if(jQuery.parseJSON(response).success==undefined){
            $form.unbind('submit');
            $form.submit();
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            return false;
    });
});
```